# Total number of distinct solution produced by polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have a function $F(x,y) = ax + by$ where $x,y$ belongs to range $[1..10^{10}]$ and $a$ and $b$ are constants, all are integers. How many distinct values can be produced by this function, please give me a upper bound or if possible a closed form .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If $a=0$, then $F(x)$ is a constant function, i.e. for every $x$, $F(x)$ is equal to $by$, so only one value can be produced by $F$.

If $a\neq 0$, then $F(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ if $x_1\neq x_2$, meaning that the number of distinct values of $F$ is equal to the number of different values of $x$ you can plug into it.

---

After edit:

One upper bound for the number of possible values is, of course, $10^{20}$, since that is how many different numbers you can plug in. If $a=1, b=10^{10}$, then you can also show that if $(x_1,y_1)\neq (x_2, y_2)$, then $F(x_1,y_1)\neq F(x_2,y_2)$, meaning that the upper bound is as good as it gets (in general).

Comment: I am really sorry ,there was a typo ,edited question

Comment: @nikhilbhr And I edited my answer.

Comment: If possible can you give some strict lower bound on it

Comment: @nikhilbhr If $a=b=0$, then you only get one possible number, and that is $0$. Therefore, $1$ is the lower bound.